# iReport + UTF-8

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have some utf-8 characters in jasperreports template. In iReport editor everything fine.
But after compiling the output PDf can not draw the valid unicode characters and draws ? instead.

How can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` header in your jrxml file? Are you using the [Font Extensions](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: You can read this [topic](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/unicode/index.html#unicode) about `Unicode` support

Comment: I have added Font Extentions jar, but it didn't help

Comment: What PDF encoding did you set in the Font Extension? It should probably be Identity-H.

Comment: Where should I set this option?

Comment: Go ahead and accept your own answer so that it shows up as an answered question in searches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to enable unicode support in output PDF file you have to:

1. Add jasperreports-fonts-x.x.x.jar to project's classpath
2. In iReport select external font for textboxes and static text elements. Usually, it is DejaVu fonts

This is solution for latest versions of JasperReports (tested on 4.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

if you have problems displaying UTF-8 characters in the pdf, no need to do anything! Just change the font of the cells in the table from sanserif to Dejavu sans. thats it.